# How can set auto increment index value for a column which is not a primary key form the fluent mapping in EF

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a table, in that table, there has a column and I want to increment this value automatically like the primary key, but this will start from 1000 and as we started inserting data to the table the will be incremented by 1. For example, if the last column value is 1000, next will be like 1001,1002 and so on

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this from GUI, go to properties of that field, and set IdentitySeed to 1000

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can you please shear the procedure

Comment: Run this query: DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[TableName]', RESEED, 1000);

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev: Question is tagged MySQL. CHECKIDENT  Is MSSQL

Comment: @Tseng thank you for reply, right way is: mysql> ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev: Still incomplete. iirc older versions of MySQL don't support auto increment on non-primary keys at all (read the question!) and new one require at least an index. And on top of that, the question is about how to do it in EntityFramework (or EF Core), so your answer can't be anymore wrong

Comment: Thank you guys but can't find anything for EF6 , where I can execute this form code level, not using the SSMS